# How to deal with MVC controllers using angular 5?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, angular5, asp.net-core-2.0

I am trying to build my first app using angular 5 and .Net core 2 API in visual studio 2017. I am using angular 5 for the client-side, and to maintain data-access, security, authorization ... I am creating Web API controllers using .Net core 2 which will be called from angular I succeeded to implement both (angular and .net APIs) in the same project;

After searching for multiple days of how to generate reports in my solution, I found multiple tools (third parties) that will help me to create reports and export them to pdf, images, excel files ... and they can be displayed as PDF or HTML  in the browser pages; Now the third parties that I found work with .net Core, and all templates are MVC templates, so when a Controller is called --> a view is returned displaying a filled cshtml page;

My problem is the below:

With angular I know how to call an API controller to return data using CRUD operations, but I don't know how to deal with MVC controllers in order to return the report page filled in the server side using .NetCore and a third party. Any suggestions?
I other words:

1. How to add MVC Controller to my solution and what is the necessary configuration of it in startup.cs file?
2. How to call it from the client side using angular 5 on a button click?

////// templates .net Core 2  API //////

Below is a template of a controller API:

```
  [Route("api/test/")]
  [Produces("application/json")]
  //[Authorize]

  public class TestController : Controller
  {

    private IConfiguration _config;

    public TestController(IConfiguration config)
    {
      _config = config;
    }

    [HttpGet("GetNames")]
    public IEnumerable<string> GetNames()
    {          
      string[] lst= { "A", "B", "C"};
      return lst;
    }
}
```

////// templates angular 5 calling API //////

// TestService code //

```
import { Injectable, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Router } from '@angular/router'; 
import { Person } from '../person';
import { HttpClientModule, HttpHeaders, HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { ErrorObservable } from 'rxjs/observable/ErrorObservable';
import { catchError, retry } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';

const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'Bearer Generatedkey'
  })
};

@Injectable()
export class TestService {

  constructor(private _http: HttpClient) {
  }

  getNameslst() {   

    return this._http.get('/api/test/GetNames', httpOptions)
      .pipe(
        catchError(this.handleError)
      );  
  }

  private handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {

    if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
      // A client-side or network error occurred. Handle it accordingly.
      console.error('An error occurred:', error.error.message);
    } else {
      // The backend returned an unsuccessful response code.
      // The response body may contain clues as to what went wrong,
      console.error(
        'Backend returned code ${error.status}, ' +
        //`body was: ${JSON.stringify(error.error)}`);
        'body was: ${error.error}');
    }
    // return an ErrorObservable with a user-facing error message
    return new ErrorObservable(
      'Something bad happened; please try again later.');
  };    

}
```

// app component ts code //

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import { TestService } from '../app/test.service';
import { Person } from '../person';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  public apiValues: string[] = [];

  constructor(public http: Http, private _testService: TestService) {

  }  

  ngOnInit() {

   this.getnames();   
  }

  getnames() {
    this._testService.getNameslst().subscribe(
      data => this.apiValues = data
    )
  }

}
```

Comment: Take a look at swagger. With swagger you can create your .NET backend and then generate a typescript client for that backend which then can be used inside your angular app.

Comment: use filesaver.js to return pdf or excel file after generating the report in .NET api. You can generate the report in API also. Actually in .NET core there is only `Controller` for both MVC and web api. In other words there are no MVC specific controller in .NET Core. You can all the API like you are calling now then use filesaver.js to show the download option after returning the file as Blob or ArrayBuffer from API.

Comment: @Niladri thank you for your declaration, I have found an example for .net core controller that return a view. The way calling it from client side : <a href="../api/controller/method" target:"_blank" > test </a> , in this way the view will be displayed in a new tab. It is working and satisfying my needs, but is it the safest way , specially with the presence of angular 5?

Comment: @H.Al in presence of angular5 all the html related and view related stuff should be handled in client side using angular unless there is specific requirement for server side checking before html renders. Hence you are supposed to use API for data interaction only in angular.

Comment: @Niladri you're right, but the problem here is that the library that I am using needs a view to implement all report stuff , and using .net core the view will be converted to excel, pdf .... Take a look at jsreport library here:  https://github.com/jsreport/jsreport-dotnet-example-webapp?files=1  ;I am completely convinced with my soltion, as I don't need the angular 5 in my view, and I just need to return the report to be displayed in a new tab in my browser. Otherwise all will be handled in client side and the api will return data only